Soundcloud Widget finish event on multiple tracks
I am using Soundcloud widget api to play
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#resources

This event to detect song finish works:
SC.Widget.Events.FINISH

However it will fire on every song end even if you try to play whole set which has multiple tracks, for example:
https://soundcloud.com/apresskisocial/sets/apres-ski-social-fm

I dont use the api to retrieve actual tracks so I dont know the content. How can I know then the last song in set finished?
